# extract DOM element with cherrio

Tags: jquery

This Meteor server code fails to extract the text "789" using the cherrio object $ as the [docs](https://github.com/cheeriojs/cheerio#nextselector) suggests.

```
$('td[headers=x]').each(function() {
  console.log($(this).next().html().trim());                  //=> 456
  console.log($(this).next('td[headers="y"]').html().trim()); //<-- fail
});
```

```html
<td headers="x" class="bodyTextSmall">
  123
</td>
<td headers="xx" class="bodyTextSmall">
  456
</td>
<td headers="y" class="bodyTextSmall">
  789
</td>
```

Any idea why? Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`.next()` will only return the *immediate* next sibling - if a selector is used then it must match. Your `headers="yy"` is not the immediate next sibling but the second next. Use `.siblings()` with the selector instead:

```
$(this).siblings('td[headers="y"]').first().html().trim()
```

Comment: please see the edit after trying this many times before I posted the question.